# How to get data from EditText when it is using in linearlayout

Tags: android

I am working with android `LinearLayout` and i am adding a `TextView` programmicataly and then on `TextView` click add an `EditText` in `View`. Now I want to get data at then end on button click from all added `EditText`s in layout. here is my coding through which i am working.

```
TextView addMoreText = new TextView(this);
        addMoreText.setText("Add More Ingredients");
        addMoreText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        addMoreText.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        addMoreText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.add, 0);
        addMoreText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final EditText editTextItem = new EditText(SearchRecipe.this);
                editTextItem.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.cross, 0);
                editTextItem.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                editTextItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        parentLayout.removeView(editTextItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                parentLayout.addView(editTextItem, 0);
            }
        });

        parentLayout.addView(addMoreText);

 searchRecipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

i want to get all the data from `EditText` on searchRecipe click

Comment: and it's not working, or?

Comment: maintain an arraylist of edittexts when you add them in layout then iterate through that list and get your texts on button click.

Comment: As Taiha said, or set an id to the edittext and save that one to a sparsarray. And do it like he said

Comment: @Memme Can you post it in answer. I am not getting the idea

Answer (score 0):

Assign the id to the `EditText`:

```
editTextItem .setId({yourId});
```

Then inside `searchRecipe` `onClick` method, invoke:

```
EditText editTextItem = (EditText) parentLayout.findViewById({yourId});
```

And then use it as you want.

Comment: My mistake, assign id to EditText and not TextView. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add an arraylist and put the edittexts in it to keep track of them.

```
ArrayList<EditText> etList = new ArrayList();
```

In onClick of textview just add to it at the end.

```
etList.add(editTextItem);
```

In searchReciepe go through your list.

```
for(Edittext et : etList){
    et.getText();
    [...]
}
```

Edit: Obviously remember to remove it from the List on remove.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int EDITTEXT_ID = 1;

private List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

// Add Edittext programmatically in your view

    private void addView() {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setId(EDITTEXT_ID);
            EDITTEXT_ID++;
            editText.setText("Hello there " + EDITTEXT_ID);

            editTextList.add(editText);
            lnvEditText.addView(editText); // lnvEdittext is my LinearLayout which is added in XML file
        }

// Get values of every Edittext on click of button

for(int i=0; i<editTextList.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("All Values=", editTextList.get(i).getText().toString());
                }
```